# Unity Serialize / De-serialize List of List of List

Tags: c#, json, list, parsing, unity-game-engine

I'm currently struggling with JSON parsing.

My json file has been generated with Construct 2, it contains json files (maps) inside this one json (map pack)

Here's an example of a map pack (contains only one map)

```
{"c2array":true,"size":[1,1,1],"data":[[["{\"c2array\":true,\"size\":[22,9,1],\"data\":[[[\"wall\"],[0],[0],[10],[480],[0],[0],[0],[0]],[[\"wall\"],[0],[470],[860],[10],[0],[0],[0],[0]],[[\"wall\"],[850],[0],[10],[470],[0],[0],[0],[0]],[[\"wall\"],[10],[0],[840],[10],[0],[0],[0],[0]],[[\"wall\"],[160],[190],[110],[140],[0],[0],[0],[0]],[[\"wall\"],[340],[280],[140],[130],[0],[0],[0],[0]],[[\"wall\"],[520],[120],[190],[150],[0],[0],[0],[0]],[[\"plateform\"],[415],[140],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]],[[\"plateform\"],[195],[160],[0],[0],[0],[1],[5],[5]],[[\"launcher\"],[415],[280],[0],[0],[0],[0],[5],[1]],[[\"ray\"],[15],[90],[0],[0],[0],[0],[5],[1]],[[\"spawn\"],[365],[265],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]],[[\"mine\"],[465],[280],[0],[0],[0],[0],[5],[0]],[[\"plateformspike\"],[65],[350],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]],[[\"plateformspike\"],[185],[390],[0],[0],[0],[1],[10],[2]],[[\"spike\"],[520],[185],[0],[0],[270],[0],[0],[0]],[[\"spike\"],[545],[270],[0],[0],[180],[0],[0],[0]],[[\"spike\"],[635],[270],[0],[0],[180],[0],[0],[0]],[[\"spike\"],[710],[175],[0],[0],[90],[0],[0],[0]],[[\"spike\"],[645],[120],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]],[[\"spike\"],[615],[470],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]],[[\"flag\"],[225],[190],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0],[0]]]}"]]]}
```

Now to load this json file i'm using the follow C# script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.IO;
using System;

public class mapLoad : MonoBehaviour {
    public string jsonString;
    public C2Map valeur;


    public bool c2array;
    public List<int> size;
    public List<List<List<string>>> data;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        jsonString = File.ReadAllText(Application.dataPath + "/Maps/MapFiles/Test/document.json");
        C2Map valeur = C2Map.CreateFromJSON(jsonString);
        c2array = valeur.c2array;
        size = valeur.size;
        data = valeur.data;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }
}
[System.Serializable]
public class C2Map
{

    public bool c2array;
    public List<int> size;
    public List<List<List<string>>> data;

    public static C2Map CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonUtility.FromJson<C2Map>(jsonString);

    }
}
```

Everything before the "data" field works but once it goes to data, the public variable gets destroyed, I've tried different methods but it either return null or destroy the variable, no errors, nothing

Comment: The issue  likely has nothing to do with your json. The reading part is likely failing since it's returning null. Where did you put the json file you are trying to read?

Comment: Hey! thanks for replying, my file is inside my unity folder, the file is indeed getting read because it's filling up c2array and size bool/list but not data (completly removing the inspector variable)

Comment: your json file has some issues on data , its actually an array of array of a single string, you can see for yourself using online tools like https://jsoneditoronline.org/

Comment: It was done like that on purpose, basically, i'm storing maps as a single string then load the string as a new json from the array; Right now on Unity  i just want to load the string as a string, not serialize it

Comment: *"the public variable gets destroyed, i've tried different methods but it either return null or destroy the variable, no errors, nothing"*. Which ones?

Comment: Used things like string[][][] ; honestly i don't remember very well what i  used to get the blank string

Comment: if your json file only contains one map data why do you serialize it in this way instead of a simple string ?

Comment: Hi, this is a "test" json just to load one map, all my "map packs" contains up to 8 maps (instead of one in this case)

Answer (score 3):

You have List of List of List variable:

```
public List<List<List<string>>> data;
```

The `JsonUtility` API does not support this. `JsonUtility` only supports simple types. If you try to serialize a class that contains that variable above, you will get `[]` and likely null when you try to de-serialize it.

You have two options:

**1**.Write a wrapper for the `List<List<List<string>>>`

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ListWrapper
{
    public List<ThirdList> secondList;
}

[System.Serializable]
public class ThirdList
{
    public List<string> thirdList;
}
```

then

declare it as  `public List<ListWrapper> data;` in your `C2Map` class.

**2**.Use *Newtonsoft.Json* the forked version for Unity. You can get that [here](https://github.com/SaladLab/Json.Net.Unity3D). The standard *Newtonsoft.Json* wouldn't work in Unity.

Comment: But when I do something like ThirdList lw = secondList[i] and then I loop on lw. I get an error saying "foreach statment cannot operate on variable because does not contain getenumarator". Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

doing some reverse engineering clears out JsonUtility of Unity has a weird behavior with nested arrays and return nulls .
but you can make use of newtonsoft json deserializer, it supports wide variety of .Net versions including 3.5 for unity.

simply put the dll file in Plugins folder and it wont return null anymore:

```
public static C2Map CreateFromJSON(string jsonString)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<C2Map>(jsonString);
    }
```

https://www.newtonsoft.com/json